# LINQ Group By or JOIN with OrderBy

Tags: entity-framework, linq, group-by

i have two tables

1) BankAccount -> Fields (BankAccountID, Name) 
2) BnkTransaction -> Fields(ID,Amount,TransactionType,Total,BankId)FK (BankId)

here is the picture of both tables
[Database tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrfjF.jpg)

what i'm trying to do is: i need Name, Amount,Credit or Debit(transactiontype),Total.
the result should be grouped by name like this by using Entity Framework LINQ

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OSSI8.jpg)

HERE is my code which i tried, however i am rather not sure how would i get the desired output, by using group by? if so then how?

```
 var joinResult = Entity.BnkTransactions
 .Include("BankAccounts")
 .Select(x => new
 {
 Name = x.BankAccount.Name,
 Amount = x.Amount,
 Credit = x.TransType == 1 ? x.TransType : 0,
 DEBIT = x.TransType == 2 ? x.TransType : 0,
 Total = x.Total
                             }).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

            foreach (var item in joinResult)
            {
                string credit = item.Credit == 1 ? "Credit" : "---";
                string Debit = item.DEBIT == 2 ? "Debit" : "---";
                Console.WriteLine("Name:-{0} Amount: {1} Credit: {2} DEBIT: {3} 
    Total: {4}", item.Name, item.Amount, credit, Debit,item.Total );
            }
```

Please help me how can i achieve this ?

Comment: I'm sure you tried. Please show your efforts --even if they failed-- so we can see where you're stuck.

Comment: i've updated the question @GertArnold

Comment: What does your current code give you, and how is that different from what you want?

Comment: my current code gives the desired output but the name also prints multiple times as long as there are matching records,
but i want to the output like i shared in the output image
and besides that i wanted to know if this can be achieved by using groupby or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a group by, something like this:

(not tested)

```
 var joinResult = Entity.BnkTransactions
 .Include("BankAccounts")
 .GroupBy(x => x.BankAccount.Name, (key, g) => new 
 {
     Name = key,
     Transactions = g.ToList()
 }).OrderBy(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

This should get you an anonymous type with one name and a list of transactions attached to it.

See if you can loop through that to output the results you need.

Comment: can you tell me how to iterate through the Transactions = g.ToList()? since i tried it using nested foreach but that too not working,
i'm trying like this
foreach (var item in joinResult)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}", item.Name);
                foreach (var resultset in item)
                {
                    
                }
            }

Comment: something like 'foreach (var item in joinResult) { foreach(var resultItem in item.Transactions ) { // do stuff } }'